# .NET what is the goal to cast an object to... object?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm-light

I was reading the source code of MvvmLight, and I've seen this function in ViewModelBase.cs:

```
protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler changedEventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (changedEventHandler == null)
        return;
    changedEventHandler((object) this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

I don't see why there is a cast here, but because this function is critical in MvvmLight, I'm guessing there is an advantage of doing so...

Comment: Maybe just to make it clear for the reader that `this` will be treated as `object` in the event handler.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be subject to ambiguity issues, etc. Perhaps just author's preference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking at the code through `Reflector` you'll always see strange stuff like this because Visual Studio lets you take short-cuts that the compiler works out for you, like passing a type as object without casting it to object.

But to answer your question, the eventhandler requires an object, so it passes `this` as `(object)`

Comment: You're right, I've checked the source code from codeplex, and the cast doesn't appear! Actually Resharper regenerates the code by reflection, I thought that the source was downloaded from the original

Comment: So, what could be the goal of the `Reflector` to show a cast in generated code??

Comment: @CSharpVJ - Reflector simply shows you what the compiled code looks like. It doesn't make decisions as to whether or not a cast is needed.  The compiler makes those decisions but allows the developer to omit them in source.

Comment: @ChrisGessler Ok, and again so `C# compiler` does this as it is a *statically* compiled language

Comment: @CSharpVJ - I'm guessing it does this because it is a TYPE SAFE language, but I don't know enough about the compiler to say one way or another.  I just know that Visual Studio lets you pass stuff around without specifying the type, but once it's compiled, you'll see the type cast in the reflected code.

Answer (score 2):

An advantage for doing this **could be** because there are one or more overloads of the `changedEventHandler` method and the type of `this` would normally call a more specific overload, but in this instance the caller wants to ensure that the `object` overload is chosen.

This is a hypothetical conjecture - it may or may not be the actual reason. :-)

Comment: `changedEventHandler` is a delegate, which I didn't think could have overloads.

Comment: @Lukazoid - Good point. It would be a good answer if it were a regular method, but I guess my hypothesis just went up in smoke. :-)